# Creating Array of Strings with hard coded value in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dictionary

I have created the array of string with hard-coded values as below :

```
char dev_string[3][3][15] = {{"item01","item02","item03"},
                                 {"item11","item12","item13"},
                                 {"item21","item22","item23"},
                      };

int main()
{

   printf("string 00 = %s \n",dev_string[0][0]);
   printf("string 01 = %s \n",dev_string[0][1]);
   printf("string 02 = %s \n",dev_string[0][2]);


   printf("string 10 = %s \n",dev_string[1][0]);
   printf("string 11 = %s \n",dev_string[1][1]);
   printf("string 22 = %s \n",dev_string[1][2]);


   printf("string 20 = %s \n",dev_string[2][0]);
   printf("string 21 = %s \n",dev_string[2][1]);
   printf("string 22 = %s \n",dev_string[2][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Aim is to create a dictionary in C at the end.Instead of hard-coding i want a pointer based implementation because in future I have to keep adding the items to this string.
More over I want to access these strings using some index, which I think I can by providing the row number(0,1 or 2).
I am not getting the right way to do it with pointers.What will be other convenient way to do it with pointers ( single or pointer to two dimension?)

Comment: `sensor_string` is defined as 3D but you use it in your code as 2D?  What is the deal with that?

Comment: `char* [3][3] sensor_string = <your strings>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because `sensor_string[x][y][z]` is a `char` a OP wants a `char*`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Because OP wants to print strings and `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char`.

Comment: Your usage is valid, but as you said, there might be different representations too. Maybe if you elaborate a little more about what you're trying to achieve and what seems wrong to you in this structure, we can help more.

Comment: `struct dic { char *word; char *description; }` ... `struct dic *d = malloc(num_of_word * sizeof(*d));`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  An *n* dimension array of chars is an *n-1* dimension array of strings.

Comment: @JimBalter Not if the n-1 arrays are not null-terminated ;)

Comment: Yes, even then ... because "string" here is actually a 15-char array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*sensor_string)[3][3];

for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 3; ++j) {
        sensor_string[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*sensor_string[i][j]) * (strlen("item") + 3));
        strcpy(sensor_string[i][j], "item");
        char* num = malloc(sizeof(*num) * 3);
        sprintf(num, "%d", (i*3 + j + 1));
        strcat(sensor_string[i][j], num);
    }
}
```

Comment: `malloc(10)`? Strange?

Comment: even this :   sensor_string[i][j] = malloc(10) seems suspicious !